# How to move an application based on two linked docker containers to another host?

Tags: docker

I'm looking forward to moving an application based on two linked contianers to a different host. The first container comes from an official MySQL image. The second container comes from an official Wordpress image. WP container is linked to the MySQL container.

These containers have evolved over time. Different templates and data. I'd like to migrate the containers to another host. Right now, if I stop the containers I only have to issue a `docker start mysql` and a `docker start wp` and all the context (links, ports, config, wahtever...) is maintained. I don't have to specify which ports I expose, or what links are in place.

What I would expect, and I don't know if docker offers, is to:

1. export the containers
2. move them to the new host
3. import the container in the new host
4. in the new host issue a `docker start mysql` and a `docker start wp`

Is this possible? If not what would be the way to get the exact same infraestructure up and running in another host?

I have tried using export/import and save/load. In both cases **what you get imported is an image**, not a container.

Comment: Suggestions: would it help to create an [ambassador container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/ambassador_pattern_linking/) (inter-host linkage)?  Or use [flocker](https://clusterhq.com/flocker/introduction/) (migrate data)?

Comment: Yes, maybe as a follow up. But the question here is how to move a container, not an image, and get it up and running in the same way as in the original host. That is, with a simple docker start.

Comment: I thought the problem had something to do with the fact that your "application" linked to multiple containers.  Based on your followup, it instead sounds like you're confused about Docker "Save" vs. Export".  You "save" an *image*; you "export" a *container*: http://tuhrig.de/difference-between-save-and-export-in-docker/  Q: What part of this isn't working for you?  It sounds like 1) you want to export Container1 and Container2, 2) you might want to create a new "ambassador container" (with your links), and export it, then finally 3) import all three containers to the new host(s).

Comment: Option 1 is the right one. I have tried export/import and issuing a run statements using the --link option. Seems like some state is lost. One of the images is a Wordpress and when accessing the exposed port it prompts me for configuring WP from scratch instead of serving the website that shoul be in the container.